# Why are the sons of Dishohn listed twice?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, vayishlach

[Breishit 36:26 and 36:28](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9597&st=&pgnum=466) list the sons of Dishohn twice. Why is there a break of 1 verse in the middle, instead of including all the children together in one verse?

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken, I believe the two verses in question refer to two different individuals, Dishon and Dishan. Some translations may incorrectly state both names as Dishan, but if you look at Bereshith 36, verse 21 you will see both names are listed among the seven sons of Seir, the Horite.
But the best source, of course, is the Hebrew that spells it all out for you. Check out this same verse 21:
 וְדִשׁוֹן וְאֵצֶר וְדִישָׁן = "and **Dishon**, and Etzer and **Dishan**" speaking of the last three children of Seir. 
The nekudot, or Hebrew vowels points, helps in the pronunciation of the word. I Hope this answers the question.
Also Dishon and Dishan engender different children.